# How can I resolve this error message so I can query QuickBooks using QODBC's VBDemo?

Tags: ms-access, quickbooks, qodbc

I'm trying to use QODBC's VBDemo program, that is found in the installation folder, to connect to QuickBooks for the first time. I've been following QODBC's [tutorial](https://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/2340/49/how-to-connect-to-quickbooks-for-the-first-time) to achieve this.

At the end of the 'Running VB Demo' section, I get to the point where I select 'QuickBooks Data' from 'Machine Data Source' and click 'OK' before getting a [Can't Open QuickBooks error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcFkW.jpg).

There aren't many posts about this problem, but I've tried using Task Manager suggested by [this person](https://community.intuit.com/questions/1187290-can-t-start-quickbooks-quickbooks-already-has-a-company-file-open-error) to close duplicate QB, restarted my computer, but the problem persisted.

How can I resolve this error message so I can query QuickBooks using QODBC's VBDemo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the following:

http://qodbc.com/links/2340
http://qodbc.com/links/2512

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

1) Ensure you don't specify a company fine.

2) Don't run QuickBooks or VBDemo 'As Admin'.

3) Ensure you're logged into the 'Admin' account in QuickBooks.

This allowed VBDemo to run and query QuickBooks properly.